# Cloudwatch alarm for 2 days period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

As per the AWS warning we can only choose max "one day" period for setting the alarm. But In my case I need to set the period of alarm is 2days. which is not allowed by AWS.

**Use case:-** This is related to the ETL job, We received the data at one bucket and send one flag to cloudwatch say "1"(when we received successfully else "0"), and then next step, this data will go for the further process, which is not immediately and also send flag 1 or 0 .

So we created math expression in cloud watch which help us to know that both the condition is satisfied or not

**IF(m2 > m1, 1, 0)**
**M2:-** NewSourceDataArrived
**M1:-** TotalRowsWritten

So is there any way or hack to achieve this?

Comment: No there is no way. You need fully custom solution for that.

Comment: any example tool or process

Comment: @me25 Please Edit your question to tell us more about your use-case, to see whether we can offer an alternative approach. Let us know what you are trying to measure and why you are seeking a 2-day period.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any example.